# Toast method makeText() not solved

Tags: android

getting error while working with `Toast` and `makeText()` method

```
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.RatingBar;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 public class RateME extends Fragment {


public RateME() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rate_me, container, false);
    final RatingBar ratingBar_default = (RatingBar) v.findViewById(R.id.ratingbar_default);
    ratingBar_default.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
         if (rating > 2 )
```

getting error here 
i tried

```
 Toast toast = Toast.makeText(RateME.this, "Value of:" + String.valueOf(rating), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

and also tried

```
Toast toast = new Toast.makeText(RateME.this, "Value of:" + String.valueOf(rating), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    {
                 Toast.makeText(RateME.this, "Value of:" + String.valueOf(rating), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }
                else
             {
                 //Toast.makeText(RateME.this, "here"+String.valueOf(rating),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
            }
        });

    return v;
    }

 }
```

here is logcat

> Error:(35, 23) error: no suitable method found for
>   makeText(RateME,String,int) method Toast.makeText(Context,int,int) is
>   not applicable (actual argument RateME cannot be converted to Context
>   by method invocation conversion) method
>   Toast.makeText(Context,CharSequence,int) is not applicable (actual
>   argument RateME cannot be converted to Context by method invocation
>   conversion)

Comment: fragment is not a `Context` you need to pass the activity

Comment: please do some searching before asking the question here.. its a 5 year old question and you have tons of answers

Comment: @DJphy Apology sir i have posted it after searching it..i am working on this error from last three days ...as the suggested answer i also mention that i tried that too but that time it was't working so after all attempts i thought to putt it here...Apologies again..

Comment: it was not ur fault.. but its the answer's fault.. they r few people who are ruining stackoverflow policies for votes :) chill

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use **getActivity()** instead of **RateME.this** in fragment

```
 Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Value of:" + String.valueOf(rating), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Try this way in fragment.

Comment: @rushDroid...tried this too at that was not working but now its working thank you

Comment: your welcome@FaridRaja if its working for you than mark as right :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this as you are using fragment:

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Value of:" + String.valueOf(rating), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```